# Encrypting request body using .pkr public key while making an API call

Tags: ruby, pgp

I'm creating a sample script to hit a client API. Client shared a .pkr public key for encrypting request body while making an API call. I didn't find any gems supporting it. Any thoughts on how to get it done?

Here is the sample script, where I need `request_body_params` to be encrypted using a .pkr public key.

```
require 'faraday'
require 'json'

conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'https://XXXXXX.com') do |faraday|
    faraday.response :logger       
    faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter  
end
request_body_params = '{
    "token":"XXXXXX",
    "person_id":XXXXXX,
    "meetingStatus":"X"
}'
response = conn.post do |req|
    req.url '/XXXXXX'
    req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    req.body = request_body_params
end
```

Comment: this needs formatting

Comment: @AkberIqbal Thanks for feedback. I formatted it correctly now.